# Intent onActivityResult into another Activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I would simply like to know if I can handle on onActivityResult() from another class besides the one it is called in?

So if I have Activity A then Activity B.

Activity B calls `onActivityResult(i, 1)`.

Could Activity A handle this response Like so

```
onActivityResult(){
   if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
      switch(requestCode){
case 1:
//handle data of image path.
break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FLow is like this:

A Means Class 1
B Means Class 2

A.startActivityForResult() -> B.setResult() -> A.onActivityResult()

Comment: on B, what would setting the result really do? Would I still return to A?

Comment: A starts the Activity B -> 
B sets the Result of its Activity ->
A gets the Result of B

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you...not what im looking for then but good information, seemed hard to figure out.